# How to adjust paragraph spacing between header and top of page?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a header at the top of the page. There is an image at the top of a page body. The problem is that I need 8 pts of space between that image and the header. I defined a style for that.

The paragraph below the image works fine, but the one before the image doesn't. I do not want to add an empty line before the image.

Desired output:
[image: paragraph needed]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is normal behavior for Word. You just need to make some adjustments to your paragraph properties.

1. Make sure your picture properties are set to `In Line with Text`.
2. Place your cursor to the left of the picture and type your
   paragraph. The text should appear above the picture.
3. At the end of the paragraph press <kbd>Enter</kbd> once (this does not enter a blank line).
4. Highlight the paragraph and set `Spacing` to `8pt` (you will have to
   type the value).

[image]

You should now have 8pt spacing after the paragraph.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, but I think you misunderstood my question. I have no text in front of my my image. The only in front of it is the headline. And I need a space of 8pts between that image and the headline.The Spacing before the image just does not work without text it seems.

Comment: You may want to clarify your question because you state "*The problem is that I need a paragraph with 8 pts above that image.*" and "*I need it to be a paragraph*". Therefore, I gave you a solution with a paragraph. A blank line is not a paragraph. Please [edit] your question to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

### You can set the format for your Heading Style to have certain space after.

This has been explained in other answers.

When you want certain *space before something in the body*, you can normally set that in the paragraph style or formatting. **However, for something at the top of a page that is not at the beginning of a section, the page-before spacing has been ignored since Word 2010.**

### To have that spacing obeyed, you can add a Frame to the paragraph formatting or style. This is my writing on [using a Frame for Space-Before at the top of a page](http://addbalance.com/word/frames_textboxes.htm#SpaceBefore).

> By design, Word ignores the space setting for the paragraph without
> the Frame. The same thing happens with a column break. Word ignores
> the Space-before formatting of a paragraph style (or just paragraph
> formatting) when the paragraph is the first one on a page following a
> page break (or at the top of a column following a column break). You
> can use a Frame to get around this. The simplest method is to modify
> the Style:
>
> [image: screenshot]
> You would want a borderless frame and to have the space-before
> paragraph formatting that you need.
>
> [image: screenshot of dialog box]
>
> Another workaround for this problem is to get your document into
> compatibility mode and check the option to allow space before. See
> Suzanne Barnhill's response in [this thread](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-do-i-get-before-spacing-to-work-after-a-column/939564e7-0f30-4a3f-b6fd-4927b4688a8f).

Comment: Note, this is actually about a heading rather than the header.

Answer (score 0):

If your picture is at the top of the body and you need 8pt between the header text and the picture, then you need to adjust the paragraph properties of the header.

1. Open the header for editing
2. Select the header text
3. Open the paragraph properties
4. Highlight the paragraph and set Spacing to 8pt (you will have to
   type the value).

[image]

This will result in a spacing of 8pt after the header text, leaving the desired space before the picture.

Answer (score -2):

The OP's initial question was very clear to anyone.
The answer still doesn't answer the question.  The issue isn't inside the header, it's in the body of the document.  This happens to me a lot and there are various ways to deal with it, such as adding space above the topmost content (text or graphic, makes no difference) via the Paragraph...Spacing Before (expressed in points).

Comment: Much of this should have been a comment. I edited your post to separate out the commentary and focus on the Answer portion. As a new contributor you are not yet able to add comments so are allowed certain latitude.

Comment: This answer does not answer the author's question.  It should have been submitted as a comment, or it should be edited, and ALL meta-commentary should be removed.  This answer is clearly and obviously a response to an existing answer.  *That alone is a reason to delete and downvote this answer.*  If this answer can be improved, and the answer actually answers the author's question, it shouldn't contain the words "the answer still doesn't answer the question"